# setup.py custom command apt-get throws error code 100

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, setup.py

I am create a setup.py file using the apache-beam recommended format: (Apache Beam Python 3.5 SDK 2.20.0) https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/juliaset/setup.py

All worked well when I had one apt-get install command. once I added two more apt-get installs:

Worked:

```
CUSTOM_COMMANDS = [['echo', 'Custom command worked!'],
                   ['apt-get', 'update'],
                   ['apt-get', 'install', '-y', 'unzip']]
```

Fires error on unzip installation:

```
CUSTOM_COMMANDS = [['echo', 'Custom command worked!'],
                   ['apt-get', 'update'],
                   ['apt-get', 'install', '-y', 'unzip'],
                   ['apt-get', 'install', '-y', 'default-jre'],
                   ['apt-get', 'install', '-y', 'perl']]
```

The error:

```
RuntimeError: Command ['apt-get', 'install', '-y', 'unzip'] failed: exit code: 100
```

any idea what am I missing?

thans,
eilalan

Answer (score 0):

I've recreated your scenario and got the same error as you on `ApacheBeam SDK 2.20.0` version. When I changed the version for `2.16.0` and `2.19.0` it started to work fine, without any issues.

This is how my `setup.py` file looks:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function

import subprocess

from distutils.command.build import build as _build

import setuptools

CUSTOM_COMMANDS = [['apt-get', 'update'],
    ['apt-get', '--assume-yes', 'install', 'unzip'],
    ['apt-get', '--assume-yes', 'install', 'default-jre'],
    ['apt-get', '--assume-yes', 'install', 'perl']]

class CustomCommands(setuptools.Command):
    """A setuptools Command class able to run arbitrary commands."""

    def initialize_options(self):
        pass

    def finalize_options(self):
        pass

    def RunCustomCommand(self, command_list):
        print
        'Running command: %s' % command_list
        p = subprocess.Popen(
            command_list,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        # Can use communicate(input='y\n'.encode()) if the command run requires
        # some confirmation.
        stdout_data, _ = p.communicate()
        print
        'Command output: %s' % stdout_data
        if p.returncode != 0:
            raise RuntimeError(
                'Command %s failed: exit code: %s' % (command_list, p.returncode))

    def run(self):
        for command in CUSTOM_COMMANDS:
            self.RunCustomCommand(command)

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [

]

PACKAGE_NAME = 'my_package'
PACKAGE_VERSION = '0.0.1'

setuptools.setup(
    name=PACKAGE_NAME,
    version=PACKAGE_VERSION,
    description='Test project',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    cmdclass={
        'build': build,
        'CustomCommands': CustomCommands,
    }
)
```

For now, the workaround is to use the older version of `ApacheBeam SDK`. I believe that there is a bug in `ApacheBeam SDK 2.20.0`, you can fill a [form](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to report a bug on IssueTracker.

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.

Comment: You haven't included how you create the `build` class from the `_build` module.